# For every context-free grammar, is there an equivalent grammar in Chomsky normal form?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

I thought that, for every CFG, there is an equivalent grammar in CNF. I was told this is false. Can someone explain to me why this is false and possibly provide a counter example?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Alternative_definition.  Which definition of CNF are you using?  I encourage you to ask whoever told you that to explain why they said that, and summarize their argument here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how strict you interpret "equivalent". A CFG in ChNF cannot generate the empty string. If you want to have a more precise statement:

> For every CFG $G$ there is a grammar $G'$ in ChNF such that 
>   $L(G) = L(G') - \{\varepsilon\}$.

So now we have two choices.

Either to accept the loss of the empty string, which in practise is not a big deal. Or we have to adapt the definition to make room for generating the empty string in a special way. This usually means we allow a production $S\to \varepsilon$ where $S$ is the axiom, provided $S$ does not occur as right hand side of productions.

This is a matter of taste: there is no "best" definition. Personally I think having a special production for $\varepsilon$ is not elegant, and prefer a notion of equivalence "upto the empty string".

Comment: Some definitions of CNF include $S \to \varepsilon$ (and $S$ can't appear on any right-hand-sides) for specifically this purpose.

Comment: You are right of course. Thanks. I consider that a quick hack, for people that do not want to lose the empty word.

Comment: It sure is! I think this here is a nice opportunity for learners to gain some intuition about which aspects of a model "matter".

Comment: Thanks, this helps clear up my question. Is there debate on the exact definition of CNF as to whether or not it should/can include the empty string?